# I cannot see my pen drive when I am in my boot options after pressing F12

Tags: 21.04

When I am in boot mode, I only see my windows OS boot but not my Ubuntu pen drive to install Ubuntu. I used Rufus to convert the iso to my Pendrive and when I start to reboot, I don't see my USB drive after pressing F12. What should I do? Thank you in advance

Comment: You changed the boot order in the BIOS to make the USB the first boot item?

Comment: Or perhaps press ESC, F2, F8, F9, or F12* to select the drive to Boot. * depending on make of BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set #1 partition ISO9660 in PEN Bootable

Using "Disks", choose the PEN (left), click the first partition, press Shift+F10, choose "Edit Partition", turn Bootable on, and Change...

Reboot and should start OK!